# Clarification on Digital Certificates

Tags: encryption, cryptography, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, iis

I used the `makecert` tool to create:

1. self-signed certificate
2. client certificate

These are the commands I used:

```
makecert -n "CN=MatthewCA" -r -sv MatthewCA.pvk MatthewCA.cer **for self signed certificate**

makecert -sk localhost -iv MatthewCA.pvk -n "CN=localhost" -ic MatthewCA.cer localhost.cer -sr localmachine -ss my -sky exchange -pe -b 01/01/2013 -e 01/01/2020 **for client certificate**
```

The two commands generated the following files:

1. MatthewCA.cer
2. MatthewCA.pvk
3. localhost.cer

I then installed `MatthewCA.cer` in the `Trusted Root Authorities` section in`mmc`.

The `localhost.cer` was installed in the `Personal` section in `mmc`.

When I view the certificate of `localhost.cer` from `mmc`, it says:

> You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate.

Does this mean that the certificate contains the private key?  If I send the `localhost.cer` to someone else, can they extract the private key?  If yes, how can I separate the private key from the certificate?

Comment: Certificate holds only the public key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the machine says that "*you* have the private key corresponding to this certificate", then this means that you have the private key *which corresponds* to the certificate, not that the certificate itself contains the private key.

Asymmetric keys come in pairs: the public key and the private key. They are mathematically linked to each other, but rebuilding the private key from the public key is considered unfeasible (way too expensive with existing technology). This is why the public key can be made **public**: this does not reveal the private key (which is kept private).

The **certificate** contains only the public key. The certificate is inherently public and can be shown to the whole World. When the certificate is used in SSL, it is indeed sent, as part of the protocol, to the peer. The private key, of course, remains private. In your case, the private key was generated within the entrails of Windows and *it stays there*. The `localhost.cer` file contains only the certificate.

(Unfortunately, some documentations designate by "certificate" the union of the certificate itself *and* the private key; this abuse of terminology is a great source of confusion. In the Windows world, when a certificate and a private key travel together as a file, the file follows the [PKCS#12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_%E2%99%AF12) format, also known as "PFX".)

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas :)  Thank you for taking the time to answer my question in detail :)

Comment: With regards to the .pvk file, in case it gets stolen, can they get the private key from it?  If I remember correctly, I had to enter a password when creating the .pvk file.  I assume that one has to enter the same password in order to get the private key from it.  Is that correct?